# ASP.Net Razor Page generates wrong URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I have this Page **'~/Pages/Topic/View.cshtml'** that uses a layout **'~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'** in my project. The problem is when this Page is rendered all Anchor tags generates a reference to the page itself ('~/Pages/Topic/View.cshtml')

Please, how do I fix this?
**Note: You can connect to my computer using TeamViewer on other related remote App and solve this for me.**

[image]
[image]

Below is _Layout.cshtml using the _Nav.cshtml
[image]

Comment: Need to see the Razor code in order to determine.

Comment: @user2966445 i have edited the question to include the Razor View code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a forward slash in front of the page name:

```
asp-page="/Department"
```

**Edit:**
I just tested this using the same scenario you described and it works. You must have additional code somewhere causing issues, or you are trying to use MVC with Razor Pages and it's causing issues.

[image]

Comment: @Nellymandela See my edit. Please show how you are using _Nav in Layout.

Comment: this is how i render _Nav `@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Shared/_Nav.cshtml")`

Comment: Also am using area, dont know if that is the cause.

Comment: Note that the anchor tag works well on other pages, this problem happens only when the '~/Pages/Topic/View.cshtml' is rendered.

Comment: Just tried `asp-page="/Department"` now and it worked. Dont know why it worked now.